# how to setup a socks 5 proxy server on centos

Tags: centos, proxy, socks

I need a socks 5 proxy server that can run on centos. This would use a block of IP's so that client X with IP Address zzz connects tomy proxy server with ip xxx and then to remote host with ip yyy. 

What is the best server software that I should install?

Answer (score 2):

Consider installing dante Socks 5 server: `yum install dante-server`
You should enable a 3rd party repository to install it, I use RPMForge.

Comment: am i right in thinking things like ldap are paid-addons for dante ?

Comment: There is no more `RPMForge` repo to install `dante-server` !!!!

Answer (score 0):

[ss5](http://ss5.sourceforge.net/). its not perfect, but its at least good, and free.

Comment: tempted to delete this answer as ss5 has proven itself over time to be full of bugs. I've leave the answer up, but i'd recommend using dante if possible.

Comment: And does not support UDP